# Identical Azure apps do not work in different tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I use Azure apps to sign users in to a web app and a desktop app. I also query for user information via Microsoft Graphs /user/ endpoint.
So we have to apps registered in Azure; one is a web app / api with permissions to sign users in and read all user profiles from graph. The other is a native app with permissions to the first app, and permissions to sign users in.

In one tenant, this works fine. However in the other tenant the web api har permissions to sign users in, but Graph declines access to the /users/ endpoint due to insufficient privileges. The error is: Authorization_RequestDenied, Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

However the exact same privileges work fine in another tenant. In the faulty tenant we get a token from graph but when we use the token on the user endpoint it throws the insufficient priv. error.

Signing in users via the desktop app (we use owin) works in one tenant but in the faulty one it sais that app *tenant.onmicrosoft.com/guid* does not exist in *tenant.onmicrosoft.com*
The app uri is correct in the settings and the app has the same privileges in both tenants.

We tried recreating the apps since this has solved similiar issues when developing things like this before. This time it doesnt seem to work however. Now I'm at my wits end here. Could there be some other issue blocking here?
The faulty tenant is part of a multi-tenant. However we only poll for users in one tenant as of now.

The apps have also been given consent by an admin via the azure portal. What am I missing here? How should i proceed with trying to fix this error?

Edit: I added a new directory in my tenant and it does not work in this new directory. Same error as with our clients tenant.
Working token for directory A:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFDNXVuYTBFVUZnVElGOEVsYXh0V2pUQkVOV21GUUgtZjRGS0VjYlIwU3Y1NndrdzhvSjhjbDIwX3JtZEJBc2h6eDhKT2VNZjFEbVFjNm1GUUdxZ2VSRFJZMTEzNXE3ZXJkTjlHTFZ6T3NycnlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiaTZsR2szRlp6eFJjVWIyQzNuRVE3c3lISmxZIiwia2lkIjoiaTZsR2szRlp6eFJjVWIyQzNuRVE3c3lISmxZIn0.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.prmIaq8PzXfeovQPeIYS20xvZqpjPH-DvZNwQ3v08KOhTnfFaiCkxtw2wh1B37QQDbOveYqCWRi2CE6Uwpb6zg3-tFh1ma852HDqnJHYCKPajxeW9oIewAnCagB5FzOLQRT_EbX-lEREQVcPUHSZpRNmAWEM2MOZjDnkWun_aqohf_1op7Cy40Ol_PkRzoEgmA7pbXeI28IMPW3S4a5M_hBo_MZzRbVdxuG8YQKkVMWX0wAhpLHAYbdF1Rv5sITEpBP-KHdgJkTswLs3xvIRLyXxrXobG1aVQihr7LHFoCIU0NAcCUQLS2xkePuYGRB09k7hFQsbSNxoJSywBZWk7w
```

non working token for directory B:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFDNXVuYTBFVUZnVElGOEVsYXh0V2pUUS1NMnBUdmVjYTgzUXFuVmlBWWpJX0dLNHZrMTBMYVF2dGF5SGQ0WmZDVlRySm0wSmtOVDU2UlJSU0NuUlFPU0k0aVNHdXZZZ1cxelpaTE9KTkJTVHlBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiaTZsR2szRlp6eFJjVWIyQzNuRVE3c3lISmxZIiwia2lkIjoiaTZsR2szRlp6eFJjVWIyQzNuRVE3c3lISmxZIn0.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.l_7qgXkco5FWR7pbX5rQzAtvnrb1e6xOr5byrvkYDcyNa85KmCu5b6ArfjxTmeDR82XTmYw51n2YAbWl2q8R58dqELOguddwnKkBBCiMwKsD_UvG2oX_M9ZMy-Lc8lERduolyST7D0BZSoYCNe9f0j85AXIOgXr_yMA5MrVz7qSVFKZ1if2BR9YvvMCphW2uQCrebEJAnchyxHiCb5refnhm2sfsDBRJqd5NWwK0-a956a6dC2zg59JbW55-3wezQOfXKYzC5ybzO7l1hV41EnJ4atBW6EvR2er7WyCAFb1Y1hSB_wgZSo7pC4LnQRRm9KXq-x2aSRKiUSg265K0RQ
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to receive Admin Consent for an administrator of the tenant. I'm assuming that because this happens when hitting `/users`, you've requested either `User.Read.All` or `User.ReadWrite.All`. Both of these require Admin Consent before a normal user can authenticate and provide User Consent.

I wrote an article a while back that you might find this helpful here: [User vs Admin Consent](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-user-vs-admin/). The examples target the v2 Endpoint while it sounds like you're using v1. That said, the same consent models and workflow apply to both v1 and v2.

Comment: seems like this was the issue. A person claiming to have admin rights had clicked the admin consent in the portal. However when i sent him urls with &prompt=admin_consent he got denied. What level of admin is needed to give these permissions?

Comment: Excellent question but I'm not sure if anyone other than a Global Admin is allowed to consent for the tenant like this.

Comment: We tried to let the global admin give consent but we still get the same error in graph.

Comment: What scopes are you requesting?

Comment: We get the token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/oauth2/token
We then do two different requests at different places in the app. With the simplest one simply being sending the token from the first request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com

I've tried this again now with two requests in postman side by side. Works in one tenant, not in other. Both apps in the different tenants have identical permissions.

Comment: We opened a case with Microsoft and asked them to look at it and they simply replied that everything looks fine and that it works.. But it clearly doesnt :)

Comment: Which scopes are you requesting?

Comment: We do not send anything about scopes in any of the requests. When asking for the token we simply send client secret & id and the tenant and the resource is graph.microsoft.com with grant type client_credentials. When asking for the user we simply send the token to graph

Comment: Yes, but your token still has to include scopes. If you're not requesting scopes (either in the URI or pre-registered) then none of this will work properly.

Comment: I tried adding scopes and it still does not work. Both User.Read and User.Read.All. However since it works on one tenant without scopes why shouldnt it work on the other without scopes?
The permissions are given in azure and consent has been given by the global admin.

Comment: Please include an example of a working and non-working token in your question. That will help sort out what is going on.

Comment: I've added the tokens in the question. Would it be possible to make the working app multi tenant and then search for users in both tenants? The most basic request we do is ask for a certain user (as the example in my comments)
But we also search for users and get specific attributes. Is it possible to register an app in tenant A, make it multi tenant, consent in tenant B and then search for users in tenant B ?

Comment: I also created a new directory now in my own Azure and tested and i can now recreate this error. I registered a new app in my new directory with the same permissions as the app in my regular directory but it cant fetch user info in the new directory due to insufficient privileges. Could it be a setting somewhere in the directory that stops graph?

Comment: Can you add the code and URI you're using to obtain this token? Neither of them look like I would expect them too.

Comment: I did not use code for this, i sent via postman to https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token. With parameters grant_type=client_credentials, client_id=id, client_secret=secret, resource=http://graph.microsoft.com, tenant=tenant.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: Just to clarify, you've added `User.Read.All` and/or `User.ReadWrite.All` application scopes to the App's registration and, _after adding_, you've requested Admin Consent?

Comment: Yes. First register and fix scopes then give consent.

Comment: I've also tried giving consent via an url with admin_consent and via the azure portal ui.

Comment: I can recreate this in my second directory consistently though. In my regular directory I can never recreate this problem. I use global admin in both directories with the exact same approach. One returns user information and the other complains about insufficient privs. So I'm guessing the issue is not with the apps but some setting in the directory. I can't find it however...

Comment: So i figured i would try to use the Azure graph instead of microsoft graph but I still get the same error..